# append two or more txt/html file in Unix using command other than UNIX

Tags: unix

How to append two or more txt/html file in Unix to a single file. i am aware of the usage of the cat command in this context but i am unable to use it in my code.Is there any alternative other than using cat command in UNIX?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Loads.

Python:

```
import sys
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(filename) as f:
        print(f.read(), end = '')
```

Bash:

```
for filename in "$@"
do
    echo "$(<$filename)"
done
```

PHP:

```
array_shift($argv);
foreach ($argv as $filename) {
    echo file_get_contents($filename);
}
```

Node.js:

```
var fs = require("fs");
for (var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i += 1) {
    process.stdout.write(fs.readFileSync(process.argv[i]));
}
```

The list goes on. There's a way to do this in every programming language with support for file I/O. Every single one of these programs follows the same pattern:

```
for each filename:
    read filename's contents
    output what was just read
```

If you can do this in your programming language, you can implement your feature.